# Pascal Hello World is not working

Tags: pascal

I am just trying to learn something new, so I am trying Pascal, but just simple hello world is not working with errors -

> Novy1.pas(12,3) Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "identifier WRITELN" found
>
> Error: C:\FPC\3.0.2\bin\i386-win32\ppc386.exe returned an error exitcode

**My code**

```
program Hello;

begin
  
writeln('test');
  
readln();
 
 end
```

Please help.

Comment: Don't know if this is the error, but you lack the "." after "end". Should be "end."

Comment: Well, I'd be surprised if this fixes your problem, but you need a full-stop after the "end".  Btw, which Pascal compiler are you using?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Personally I like pascal much more than any other language. It can be out of fashion for some people. I don't care what other people do. With pascal productivity + reliability are at their best.

Comment: Recommended reading: [http://wiki.freepascal.org/Console_Mode_Pascal](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Console_Mode_Pascal).

Comment: @MartynA, from the error message you can see that it is FPC 3.0.2 32 bit windows compiler. Perhaps there is a lack of declarations like `{$mode objfpc}{$H+}` or `{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}` or `Uses Classes;'`

Comment: @LURD:  Thanks, I obviously missed that

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: You're a bit out of fashion in 2017. http://embarcadero.com/products/delphi

Comment: In addition to the . after the end, if you're not going to be reading into any variables then you don't need the () after the readln.